# Custom HTML marker in Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I was trying to find a way to put custom HTML elements as markers in highcharts highmaps the way it is supported in amCharts http://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/.

Couldnt figure out for highcharts.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add markers as bubbles, defined by lat/lng.

Manual: 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon

Comment: Does highmaps only provide bubble shape?

Comment: What kind of shapes you need?

Comment: Basically, I want to customize the shape. For instance, I want dialog shape such as https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=dialog+shape&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&imgil=XBcvGmz79fDrBM%253A%253BTEAatgQcopDxeM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pd4pic.com%25252Fshape%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=XBcvGmz79fDrBM%253A%252CTEAatgQcopDxeM%252C_&usg=__ROMmUJOLlmohmoiku2vSyZAVhzw%3D&ved=0ahUKEwi43KzAtb_JAhVjJ6YKHTl3AnMQyjcIJQ&ei=xxBgVvjcKuPOmAW57omYBw#imgrc=XBcvGmz79fDrBM%3A&usg=__ROMmUJOLlmohmoiku2vSyZAVhzw%3D.

Comment: You can try to use scatter serie and define marker by image. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol

Comment: My question was in highcharts instead of <cirlce></circle> as a bubble can i add a custom html element as a bubble?